# Authorizaton Flow in identity Server 4: Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: oauth, authorization, identityserver4, hybrid

I have a grant type as hybrid which allow me to route my application to a identity server through the browser so login using single sign on for other apps.

The first stage i can request the authorization code from identity server through the authorize endpoint.

Once I have the code, i request the access / refresh token through the token point with grant_type = "authorization_code" with the code provided from the first stage.  At this stage, I received an error saying "unsupported grant type". I assumed I have not added the grant type "authorization_code" for this Client Id.

In the Identity Server database, I added both "hybrid" and "authorization_code" grant types, this doesn't work either.

Am I added the wrong grant_type for authorization_code ?

Comment: make sure you use content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 2):

`authorization_code` and `hybrid` is [one of the restricted combinations](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/Storage/src/Models/Client.cs#L346) as described in the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#incompatible-grant-types). You should prefer one of them (actually only the first one + PKCE [is preferable](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/ASPNET-Core-using-Proof-Key-for-Code-Exchange-PKCE#comment-4301134089) for today) and use in all the calls with the client.